# can you show example for this?

Tags: general-topology

Show that if $X$ is a well-ordered set, then $A=X \times [0,1)$ in the dictionary order is a linear continuum

solution link
https://onesidey.wordpress.com/2012/03/09/munkres-24/

and I wonder $\pi_1(A)$ doesn’t have a maximum element

can you show example???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s an example of what I think you’re asking for. Let

$$\begin{align*}
X&=\left\{1-\frac1{2^n}:n\in\Bbb N\right\}\cup\left\{2-\frac1{2^n}:n\in\Bbb N\right\}\\\\
&=\left\{0,\frac12,\frac34,\frac78,\frac{15}{16},\ldots,1,\frac32,\frac74\frac{15}8,\frac{31}{16},\ldots\right\}\;;
\end{align*}$$

$X$ is a well-ordered subset of $\Bbb R$.

Let $Y=X\times[0,1)$ ordered lexicographically, and let

$$A=\left\{\left\langle 1-\frac1{2^n},\frac12\right\rangle:n\in\Bbb N\right\}\;.$$

(I recommend drawing a picture at this point. $Y$ should look like a bunch of vertical line segments, one for each $x\in X$, closed at the bottom and open at the top. $A$ consists of the midpoint of each of the segments with $x$-coordinate less than $1$.)

Now

$$\pi_1[A]=\left\{1-\frac1{2^n}:n\in\Bbb N\right\}=\left\{0,\frac12,\frac34,\frac78,\frac{15}{16},\ldots\right\}\;;$$

and this set clearly does not have a maximum element. However,

$$X\setminus\pi_1[A]=\left\{1,\frac32,\frac74\frac{15}8,\frac{31}{16},\ldots\right\}\;,$$

whose least element is $1$, so $\left\langle 1,\frac12\right\rangle$ is the least upper bound of $A$ in $Y$.

Comment: thanks! it is clear example!

Comment: @solafide: You’re welcome; glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

For $A$ to be a linear continuum, it needs to have two properties:

- Every bounded set needs a least upper bound
- For all $x,y\in A$ with $x<y$, there exists $z\in A$ with $x<z<y$.

For the first property, let $B\subseteq A$ be a bounded set. Let $n$ be the the smalles element of $X$ such that $\{n\}\times[0,1)\cap B\neq\emptyset$. Then, since $\{n\}\times[0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1)$, there exists a least upper bound for $\{n\}\times[0,1)\cap B\neq\emptyset$ which is also a least upper bound for $B$.

For the second property, let $x,y\in A$ with $x<y$. Then $x=a\times s$ and $y=b\times t$. If $a<b$, let $s<r<1$. Then $x<a\times r<y$. Otherwise, let $s<r<t$. Then the same result follows.

Of course this is not what you asked. I got ahead of myself. You want an example. Let $X$ be the natural numbers. then we get $A=\mathbb N\times [0,1)$ which is homeomorphic to the nonnegative reals.